# Spartacus - Component Mapping ONLY for B2B sites

Tags: spartacus-storefront

HI i'm quite new to Spartacus and one of the many tasks i have is to customize the PDP page.

However, this customization should only happen on B2B stores only.

I tried mapping components and this affect both B2C and B2B, is there a way we can only do component mapping for B2B store only?

Did this on my custom module..

```
@NgModule({
   declarations: [
   ...
   ],
   imports: [
      ConfigModule.withConfig({
      cmsComponents: {
        BreadcrumbComponent: {
          component: CustomBreadcrumbComponent
        },
        ProductAddToCartComponent : {
          component: CustomProductCartComponent
        },
      }
    } as CmsConfig)
   ]
)}
```

Tried using provideConfig but didn't work. Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Given that this is a custom module and assuming you have configured your instance to be a B2B storefront, this approach is good, however, I'm assuming you have a different 'instance' storefront which is configured to only run B2C, then I believe you can just not include that custom module that overrides the mapping. 

Do note, we have this issue https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/10251 in our backlog, which may be able to alleviate this issue problem in the future.

Comment: Although https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/10251 is on our roadmap, due to performance reasons you might *want* to build B2B and B2C storefronts separately and deploy as separate instances. Thanks to that, your B2C storefront won't contain the unnecessary JS for customized components. Only your B2B storefront will have this JS shipped to users' browsers.